# Making many scatter plots when data is in tidy (long) format with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I could not find any answers to this question.

I have a data set which has this format:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(row_number=row_number()) %>% 
  select(row_number, mpg, disp, hp, wt) %>% 
  gather(mpg, disp, hp, wt, key="key", value= "value")
```

I would like to make 6 scatter plots i.e. with all the combinations e.g. mpg vs disp; mpg vs hp etc.

[image]

Comment: In base R look at the `pairs()` function, or use the `ggpairs` function from the `GGally` package to make all combinations of ggplot2 scatterplots.

Comment: Note that both of those functions take a data frame in wide format with one variable per column so you would not need to `gather()` first.

Comment: As per qdread's comment, the following should address your problem: `<your dataset> %>% spread(key, value) %>% select(-row_number) %>% GGally::ggpairs()`